# c# NodeMouseOver Tooltip

Tags: c#, tooltip

I have the following code:

if (e.Node.Level == 2 && e.Node.Name.Contains("PI3K1003"))
                toolTip1.Show("test",_tv);

It works when I do hover the mouse over the appropriate node.  However, when I leave the treeview control and then move the mouse back onto the control, the tooltip displays straight away, even though I am not hovering over this node?

Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you told the ToolTip control to show the tip for the entire TreeView, not just the node.  Consider the TreeNode.ToolTipText property instead.